# Fail to set up project with webpack, babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bower

I am making a sample app using react, bower and webpack.

I have this `index.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom';
import AwesomeComponent from './AwesomeComponent.jsx';

    var App = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (<p> Hello React!</p>);
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I installed the following:

```
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -S
```

My `webpack.config.js` is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  loaders : [
     {
       test : /\.jsx?/,
       loader: 'babel',
       include : APP_DIR,
       query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
       }
     }
   ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

My issues is that in the `index.jsx` file I am getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/client/app/index.jsx
Module parse failed: /path/to/file/src/client/app/index.jsx Unexpected token (7:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

However, I've installed the bower packages and made bower the default loader.

Why does this still come up then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your loaders config under a "module" key.

```
...
output: {
  path: BUILD_DIR,
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?/,
    loader: 'babel',
    include : APP_DIR,
     query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
     }
  }]
}
...
```